# How to prevent proguard from repackage the injars?

Tags: jar, proguard

When giving the parameters below,

```
-injars C:\a.jar
-injars C:\b.jar
-outjars C:\Temp
```

proguard will generate processed a.jar and b.jar into C:\Temp. Very intelligent, but sometimes not necessary. Is there a way to disable proguard from packaging *.jar and copy the actual classes to C:\Temp?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to let ProGuard write unpacked output when the input is packed in jars. The closest approximation is to combine the output in a single jar:

```
-injars C:\a.jar
-injars C:\b.jar
-outjars C:\out.jar
```